# Leader lines in SLD

Tags: labeling, sld

I have point type shapefile and I want to create leader lines connecting labels with features in Styled Layer Descriptor. I spent significant amount of time searching for examples, tips etc., but I still have not found the right clue.

Is it possible at all?

I only started working with SLD recently.

Comment: I'm reasonably confident that SLD's don't support this. I can't see any hints in either the SLD spec, or the GeoServer labeling reference (which includes lots of GeoServer specific vendorOptions) http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-reference/labeling.html. It may be worth asking on the GeoServer users list to confirm.

Comment: do you have a file with point locations for the labels and the original location?